# How to copy previous number in array when Zero occurs

Tags: javascript

I have an array as below. How can previous value be copied to the array when zero occurs.

```
var array_numbers = [9,0,1,0,2,0,3];
var Result_array = [9,9,1,1,2,2,3];
```

i am able to get filter out all zeros with below code, but need to copy the previous values in the array

```
arr.filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple consecutive zeros? If so, what should the result be in that situation?

Comment: Yes , possible. Previous value where non zero was existing should be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since multiple consecutive zeros are possible, one option is to hold the last non-zero value in state:

```js
const numbers = [9, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3];

let last;
const result = numbers.map(n => last = n || last);

console.log(result);
```

Another option is to implement a “scan” that works like `reduce` but keeps every value produced:

```js
const scanl1 = (array, f) => {
    if (array.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    let x = array[0];
    const result = [x];

    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        x = f(x, array[i]);
        result.push(x);
    }

    return result;
};

const numbers = [9, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3];
const result = scanl1(numbers, (m, n) => n || m);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use of the `.map()` function, because every input needs an output, even if it changes.

```
var result_array = array_numbers.map(function(val, index, array) {
  // the OR operator will move on if val is falsy... like zero
  return val || array[index - 1];
});
```

I simplified the check, but it doesn't handle some scenarios, like if the *first* value is zero, or other falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map` instead of `.filter`, if the current index is greater than `0` you return the previous index, otherwise the current value. Not sure what you want to do with `[0, 0, 0]`...

```js
const input = [9,0,1,0,2,0,3]
const output = input.map((item, index, arr) => {
  if (item === 0 && index > 0) {
     return arr[index-1]
  }
  return item
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to filter it, since you're trying to end up with an array of the same length.

What you should do, is iterate the array, and grab the item at the previous index when a `0` is found. You can use `||` to get the last array item for the first member if needed.

```js
var array_numbers = [9,0,1,0,2,0,3];
var result = array_numbers.map(function(n, i, arr) {
  return n === 0 ? arr[(i || arr.length)-1] : n;
});

console.log(result);
```

If both the first and last are `0`, the first won't get changed.